# "Raw value for enum case is not unique" for Swift enum with Float raw values

Tags: swift, enums

According to [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html), I should be able to create a Swift enum with raw values of "strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types". But when I try:

```
enum BatteryVoltage: Float {
    case v3v7 = 3.7
    case v5v0 = 5.0
    case v7v4 = 7.4
    case v11v1 = 11.1
    case v12v0 = 12.0
}
```

... I get a compilation error:

```
Raw value for enum case is not unique
```

on the v7v4 line. It compiles fine with that one commented out. But ah, it looks unique to me. If I make the value 7.41, or 7.3 or something else it compiles fine. What's going on? Swift bug?

Comment: That looks definitely like a bug. It seems to happen if one enum value is exactly equal to "2 times another enum value" (but not an integer).

Comment: You know what, you're right. Answerify your comment and I'll accept. (And file a radar. Sigh.)

Comment: I guess this could be connected with the binary representation of a float. Maybe the equality comparison for enums is truncating some bits.

Comment: Radar filed, rdar://18878723

Comment: Now in Swfit 2, this is not an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It definitely says you *can*, but don't use floating-point values (and especially `Float`) where you're going to need to compare equality -- the precision just isn't guaranteed to be good enough. And always use `Double` unless you absolutely need to use a `Float` for compatibility reasons.

In this case, it seems like it's having trouble because (a) the third case is 2x the first case, and (b) some other factor I don't know. Using `3.3/6.6`, `3.4/6.8`, and `3.6/7.2` also gave me the issue, but `3.5/7.0` did not. However, I could get it to show up by changing the last case to `22.2` (2x `11.1`).

Here's a workaround — use a typical `Int`-based enumeration, and provide a `doubleValue` property:

```
enum BatteryVoltage: Int {
    case v3v7
    case v5v0
    case v7v4
    case v11v1
    case v12v0

    var doubleValue: Double {
        switch self {
        case .v3v7: return 3.7
        case .v5v0: return 5.0
        case .v7v4: return 7.4
        case .v11v1: return 11.1
        case .v12v0: return 12.0
        }
    }
}
```

There are some [nice additional features of enums](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/10/loopy-random-enum-ideas) you can take advantage of if they're `Int`-based.

Comment: I'm giving this to you for the blog post link—adding a method to the enum that uses the Int value to index into an array of values is a better way of achieving what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 5):

*(From my above comment:)*

That looks definitely like a bug. It seems to happen if one enum value is exactly equal to "2 times another enum value", but not equal to an integer.

More generally (as @Sulthan observed) the error occurs if the ratio of the enumeration
values is a *power of two*, such as `3.7/7.4`, `1.2/4.8`, or `1.1/17.6`, but *only*
if both values have a non-zero fractional part. So `1.5/3.0` or `1.25/5.0` do not
cause an error.

Comment: @Sulthan: You are right, not only factor 2 causes the problem but also 4, 8, 16, ...

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked.

I was assigning empty string to multiple case values in the enum. I changed that.  Make sure every case value is unique.